Problem with "r" mark encoding
This was seen on creating a new brick.se account, although this may be present in other areas of the site.
FF7, Windows 7, 32-Bit. ~21:00GMT.


Affected iOS5 as well, glad to see someone got this before me. :)

Thanks for letting us know.  Taken care of!
